# D3.js event handler on external dom element to trigger redraw of svg tree nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have a function that builds my d3 display, within it is a function called `update()` which actually deals with the nodes.

The function can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/deadlysyntax/cf6cbc10e958869a745f)

As you can see, the `svg` tree is created and then the `update()` function is run, displaying the tree nodes.

When a tree node with a certain data attribute is clicked, an `html` `form` is appended to the screen which allows a user to add data relating to that node. The user enters the data, clicks 'save' which has a `jQuery` based `event` handler attached which updates the data source.

I need to then trigger the tree to update with the node showing the new data.

I'm unsure how to trigger this `update()` function from an external function. I don't want to have to rebuild the entire tree every time, just redraw the nodes to show the new data.

Where is the gap in my understanding of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be more of a JavaScript scope issue. Is `tree_data` already exposed to other functions (e.g. in the jQuery event handler, can you `console.log(tree_data`)? If so, then we just need an external reference to `update`.

A quick way is to assign it to the global `window` scope:

```
window.update = function(source) { ...
```

Of course this isn's not optimal, but it does help us narrow down your issue.

If that works, then we just need to declare a variable outside the scope of your `build: function(tree_data)` and then inside, on [line 65](https://gist.github.com/deadlysyntax/cf6cbc10e958869a745f#file-gistfile1-txt-L65), assign it to `update`:

```
var externalReferenceToUpdate;

[...]

build: function(tree_data) {
[...]
   var update = function(source) {
   [...]
   };
   externalReferenceToUpdate = update;

   update(root);  // moved this due to function expression vs. declaration

   [...]
}
```

As you noticed, we had to move `update(root)`. This is because we've "made" the function using a different method. There's a [whole other Stack Overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) on the ways to declare functions and their scope issues. Essentially with the second way (`var name = function()`), the function is **not** "hoisted" to the top of its scope, so we had to call `update` after we assigned it to a variable.

Hope this helps!

PS In that other discussion, skim over the first answer and actually focus on the [second answer by Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/2705522).

Comment: Perfect. I simply needed to refactor the update function to a new scope which means setting all d3 "build" variables into an object that could be referenced within the update function and moving the update function out of the build function. Trust hindsight to make you feel silly.